# Stange Rspec test failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec2

I'm developing a Rails 3.2 application, with test coverage, but for some reason some of my test are failing. The same spec works for another model.

Spec are run with Rspec, FactoryGirl, Shoulda-Matchers.

This is the failing spec: http://pastebin.com/8VWCAv79

The errors are:

```
Failures:

  1) PlacesController POST create when user is logged in with valid params redirects to the created place
     Failure/Error: response.should redirect_to(Place.last)
       Expected response to be a <:redirect>, but was <200>
     # ./spec/controllers/places_controller_spec.rb:109:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) PlacesController POST create when user is logged in with valid params assigns a newly created place as @place
     Failure/Error: assigns(:place).should be_persisted
       expected persisted? to return true, got false
     # ./spec/controllers/places_controller_spec.rb:104:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) PlacesController POST create when user is logged in with valid params creates a new Place
     Failure/Error: expect {
       count should have been changed by 1, but was changed by 0
     # ./spec/controllers/places_controller_spec.rb:96:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 4.63 seconds
21 examples, 3 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/places_controller_spec.rb:107 # PlacesController POST create when user is logged in with valid params redirects to the created place
rspec ./spec/controllers/places_controller_spec.rb:101 # PlacesController POST create when user is logged in with valid params assigns a newly created place as @place
rspec ./spec/controllers/places_controller_spec.rb:95 # PlacesController POST create when user is logged in with valid params creates a new Place
```

The quite same spec are present in another file, http://pastebin.com/r8HtAwSR , and are correctly passing, without problem.

These are the controller files:

- http://pastebin.com/C40Bti0m ( failing spec )
- http://pastebin.com/AHnn3Nh0 ( working spec )

Can anyone suggest me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like the new place isn't created for some reason (my guess is, it doesn't pass validations).

Try to debug your tests. I like using [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry). Just add to your gemfile `gem 'pry'`, run bundle and then you can set breakpoints in the execution.

For example try this:

```
it "redirects to the created place" do
  post :create, {:place => valid_attributes}
  binding.pry
  response.should redirect_to(Place.last)
end
```

The execution will stop at the point, where you insert 'binding.pry' and you can check what is the last place in your terminal.

Comment: Unfortunatly this didn't helped in solving the problem... The strange thing is that the model passes all validation tests, which are run using the same factory used in the controller, so the attributes are equals...

Comment: @endorama just putting 'binding.pry' wont solve the problem -- of course. The point is once you have binding.pry there you can then EXPLORE YOUR PROGRAM to find out what's going on, you can 'cd' in and out of objects, show the source of methods, run code, etc. You have ful l access to the state of your entire program at that point, and you're in a much better position to find the root of the problem.

Comment: @endorama it's not suppose to solve your problem. It's suppose to help you find out what's wrong. Place 'binding pry' in the test, run your test suite, execution will stop at the point where you inserted binding, change to your terminal (to one, where your server is running) and try 'Place.last'. Is it what you expected? If not check your valid_attributes. Are they really valid? What will be returned if you do something like 'place = Place.new(valid_attributes); place.valid?;'. If false, check your validation errors 'place.errors' if true, the problem is somewhere else...

Comment: in any case, it really seems like your place is not created for some reason. I can't tell why from what I see, but in the first test, response code is 200. It would be 201 if the place had been created and 302 if there were a redirect. 200 means that it just rendered a site. Probably the 'new' action with validation errors. You can try to  write out 'response.body' to see, what has been rendered.

Comment: ok, so I found thee problem... is actually this line `validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => { :scope => [ :street_address, :city, :zipcode ] }` in the Place model.  

Probably more than one Place with the same name are created in the scope...

I'm using the `let!()` helper from rspec, could you have a look and give me some tips to find the problem?